# Is it possible to scan for methods with specific attributes within assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

Is it possible to scan for methods with particular attributes within the assembly? I am currently working on Visual C++ project but even C# is fine with me. I need to find all methods within currently assmebly that have a paricular attribute Eg. `[XYZ]` applied to it. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're looking for C++/CLI code to scan .Net assemblies looking for attributes, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used Microsoft Roslyn for a similar task. It should be pretty easy.

Let me know if you need any example code.

And take a look at this post too: http://blog.filipekberg.se/2011/10/20/using-roslyn-to-parse-c-code-files/

Reflection can also be used for that, the GetCustomAttributes method returns all attributes defined on the given member...

Alright, try this:

```
this.GetType().GetMethods()
```

loop trough all the methods and GetCustomAttributes

That should be it. Unfortunately I don't have Visual Studio installed on my wife's laptop :)

Comment: Hi anima, yes please. Just some sample code would be really appreciated. I am not using Roslyn. I want to use Reflection.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.  It will search any object for a particular Attribute

```
        MemberInfo[] members = obj.GetType().GetMethods();
        foreach (MemberInfo m in members)
        {
            if (m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Method)
            {
                MethodInfo p = m as MethodInfo;
                object[] attribs = p.GetCustomAttributes(false);
                foreach (object attr in attribs)
                {
                    XYZ v = attr as XYZ;
                    if (v != null)
                        DoSomething();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Given a path to an assembly:

```
static void FindAttributes(String^ assemblyPath)
{
    Assembly^ assembly = Assembly::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);

    for each (Type^ typ in assembly->GetTypes())
    {
        for each (CustomAttributeData^ attr 
            in CustomAttributeData::GetCustomAttributes(typ))
        {
            Console::WriteLine( "{0}: {1}", typ, attr);
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this will load each and every assembly you use into the Application Domain, so it might be worth calling this code in its own AppDomain each time.

Answer (score 2):

Use Reflection to Get the methods and grab the attributes